# Click isn't working in iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

My element click event works perfectly on Android, but not working in iOS. Please help me.

HTML code:

```
<div class="img-thumbnail" src="../image/<?=$Image?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-image="../image/<?=$Image?>" style="width: 100%; height: 250px; overflow:hidden; display:block; background:url('../air/w250-h250/<?=$Image?>'); background-size:100%; background-repeat:no-repeat"></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal',function(event){
     var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
     $("#imagePrv").html('<img src="'+button.data('image')+'"width="100%" height="100%">');                 
})
```

Comment: Hm, you should try to use "onclick", or jQuery ".click(function()...) to these things. Is your JS enabled?

Answer (score 2):

try using the touchstart method for IOS

$(element).on("touchstart", function (e) {

}

some usefull [tips](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-ipad-code-snippets-plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you this here:

1. Either remove the type of the js or change to `type="text/javascript"`.

---

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     // modal code.
 </script>
```